# How can I extract files with specific extension from a tar file's root directory?

Tags: debian, command-line, tar

I have a tar file. That's what its structure looks like:

```
-images.tar.gz

  -folder_0_image_1.jpg
  -folder_0_image_2.jpg
  -folder_0_image_3.png
  -...

  -folder_1

      -folder_1_image_1.jpg
      -folder_1_image_2.jpg
      -...

  -folder_2

      -folder_2_image_1.jpg
      -folder_2_image_2.jpg
      -...

  -folder_x ...
```

How do I extract all the files **from the root directory**  that have the .jpg extension?

(I'd like to extract these files: *folder_0_image_1.jpg*, *folder_0_image_2.jpg* ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude files in subfolders like this:

```
tar --wildcards --exclude='*/*' -xvzf images.tar.gz '*.jpg'
```

**Explanation:**

```
 --wildcards
```

means we specify files to extract by a wildcard, i.e. `*.jpg` - specified later

```
--exclude='*/*'
```

an option to exclude (from being selected for extraction) all entries with a `/` in them - i.e. all files in subfolders

```
-xvzf
```

eXtract, Verbose output, gunZip decompress first, archive from a File

```
images.tar.gz
```

the archive name, of course

```
'*.jpg'
```

filename pattern - we promised `tar` one, here it is - everything that ends in `.jpg`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @fff You're welcome :-)